# If $f$ is $\alpha$-Holder continuous and a.e. differentiable, does $\nabla f(x)$ necessarily blow up at most as $\lvert x \rvert^{\alpha-1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I do not see how to formulate the question precisely, but this is my best attempt.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact region and $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Holder-continuous function of exponent $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Further assume that $\nabla f$ exists in the strong sense on $\Omega - N$, where $N$ is a null set, and $\lvert \nabla f \rvert$ is $L^1$ on $\Omega$.

Now, it is of course possible that $\nabla f$ may have a singularity even on $\Omega - N$.

However, if $\lvert \nabla f(x) \rvert \to \infty $ as $x \to a$ for some $a \in \Omega-N$, is it necessarily true that $\lvert \nabla f(x) \rvert \leq C_{\epsilon} \lvert x-a \rvert^{\alpha-1-\epsilon}$ for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and a corresponding constant $C_{\epsilon}>0$?

If so, would each singular point (like the above $a$) be an isolated point in $\Omega$?

These speculations seem plausible, but I cannot justify them. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: If you just put the definition of $\nabla$ as a limit, doesn't your claim pop out directly from the Holder condition?